# Which file to customize request_handler.php

Tags: cakephp, httprequest

I need to create a custom function in request_handler.

Which file should I edit:

**core\cake\libs\controller\components\request_handler.php**

or

**app\controllers\components\request_handler.php**

I believe that core should be mantained has origin and all the changes should be made on app folder, is this right? Assuming it's correct, I should duplicate the file (from core to app) and add the functions I need or just create a new file with the new functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which versuion of Cake is this? Seems like 1.3?

You should NOT edit the core under any circumstances. It is also not good to add a function to `request_handler`.

If you need this logic all over the application just implement it in the `AppController`'s [callback functions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#request-life-cycle-callbacks).

Comment: You're right, V1.3! The function I intend to add is related to the http request, do you think I should create it only in AppController, dont't you think it makes sense to put it into request_handler? Thanks

Comment: Well yes it is better to modify the request in `beforeFilter()` for example. You should put it in `AppController` only if this is desired for all controllers.